# Is there a way to do custom tables with queries on List & Label?

Tags: sql, listlabel

I need information on a report that comes from an sql query that is introduced on design form. Is there a way to do so?

I tried to look for it on the documentation but I wasn't able to find info about this. The documentation is very laking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using C# / .NET this can easily be done using the `DbCommandSetDataProvider` class. A sample how to add a couple of tables and relations can be found [here](https://docu.combit.net/net/en/combit.ListLabel%7Ecombit.ListLabel.DataProviders.DbCommandSetDataProvider%7EAddRelation(String,String,String,String,String).html).